# 'Error: AMQJS0013E Invalid argument string for uri' when trying to connect to a MQTT server locally with Mosquitto

Tags: react-native, expo, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to work with an mqtt server for the first time and use it in a react native app (using Expo) that i'm also using for the first time ^^. I'm just trying to create a simple component and store messages for now.
In order to do so, I started a local mqtt server with the command 'mosquitto' and tried some exchanges with MQTTX and it worked.

Then, i tried to implement a component in my react native app like so :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Client, Message } from 'react-native-paho-mqtt';

const MQTTComponent = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(''); // Local state to store MQTT message

  useEffect(() => {
    // Create an instance of the MQTT client
    const client = new Client({
      uri: 'mqtt://127.0.0.1:1883',
      clientId: 'testClient',
    });

    // Function to handle received MQTT messages
    const handleMessage = (message) => {
      console.log(`Received message on topic ${message.destinationName}: ${message.payloadString}`);
      setMessage(message.payloadString); // Update the 'message' variable
    };

    // Establish the connection to the MQTT server
    client.connect()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected to MQTT server');
        // Subscribe to an MQTT topic
        client.subscribe('topic');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('MQTT connection error:', error);
      });

    // Configure the event handler for MQTT messages
    client.onMessageArrived = handleMessage;

    // Return a cleanup function to unsubscribe and disconnect on unmount
    return () => {
      client.unsubscribe('topic'); // Unsubscribe from the MQTT topic
      client.disconnect(); // Disconnect from the MQTT server
    };
  }, []); // The empty array means this code runs only once on component creation
};

export default MQTTComponent;
```

However, I get the error :

```
Error: AMQJS0013E Invalid argument string for uri.
```

I tried to change the uri but i always get the same error, I really need some help understanding this.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/robhogan/react-native-paho-mqtt/issues/41) "the uri needs a '/' at the end to be valid for some reason".

Answer (score 2):

The `react-native-paho-mqtt` is a wrapper round the Paho JavaScript client, which ONLY supports connections that use MQTT over WebSockets.

See the table at the top of https://eclipse.dev/paho/index.php?page=clients/js/index.php which states "Standard TCP Support" is not supported.

This is also evident from this line in the code:

https://github.com/robhogan/react-native-paho-mqtt/blob/9a9d40c76cdc3448180d130110854415de62976e/src/Client.js#L75

```
    if (!/^(wss?):\/\/((\[(.+)\])|([^\/]+?))(:(\d+))?(\/.*)$/.test(uri)) {
      throw new Error(format(ERROR.INVALID_ARGUMENT, [typeof uri, 'uri']));
    }
```

This tests that the URI starts with either `ws://` or `wss://`

You will need to ensure the broker you are connecting to is configured to support MQTT over WebSockets